# Complicated array sorting php

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort this json array in php but I can't figure out how to do it.

I want the latest season and latest episode on 1, latest season latest episode-1 on 2, etc.

```
$episodelist = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache/episodes.json'), true);
$episodes = $episodelist["doctor who (2005)"];
```

json array:

```
"doctor who (2005)": {
        "1": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58259\/doctor-who-extra-s01e03-robot-of-sherwood-pdtv-x264-deadpool\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E03 Robot Of Sherwood PDTV x264-DEADPOOL (124.73 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:DZ7H4EWP2XW6YRYIXEIPMULETLASGDAF&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.PDTV.x264-DEADPOOL&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "2": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58254\/doctor-who-2005-8x03-robot-of-sherwood-720p-hdtv-x264-fov\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who 2005 8x03 Robot Of Sherwood 720p HDTV x264-FoV (1.02 GB)",
            "season": "8",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:S25AOAFO5ZUGXMZ52ZI2OUD5S5TD4ZBI&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.8x03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.720p.HDTV.x264-FoV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "3": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58252\/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-720p-webrip-x264-c4tv\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek 720p Webrip x264-C4TV (203.70 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "2",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FQ6CNHRGQSRKFWIX63JGG4KWLVVOZJQX&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.720p.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "4": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58251\/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-webrip-x264-c4tv\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek Webrip x264-C4TV (81.13 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "2",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:OZ7O2O3FE7RADBGOAJEE4UMBROPO7CW7&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "5": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58248\/doctor-who-2005-s08e03-hdtv-x264-tla\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who 2005 S08E03 HDTV x264-TLA (399.11 MB)",
            "season": "8",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:SYDVQP4NMZJ5MQ2CEIOPZWUBLQWNKKHO&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.S08E03.HDTV.x264-TLA&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        }
```

The array I want it to become:

```
"doctor who (2005)": {
        "1": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58248\/doctor-who-2005-s08e03-hdtv-x264-tla\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who 2005 S08E03 HDTV x264-TLA (399.11 MB)",
            "season": "8",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:SYDVQP4NMZJ5MQ2CEIOPZWUBLQWNKKHO&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.S08E03.HDTV.x264-TLA&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "2": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58254\/doctor-who-2005-8x03-robot-of-sherwood-720p-hdtv-x264-fov\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who 2005 8x03 Robot Of Sherwood 720p HDTV x264-FoV (1.02 GB)",
            "season": "8",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:S25AOAFO5ZUGXMZ52ZI2OUD5S5TD4ZBI&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.8x03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.720p.HDTV.x264-FoV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "3": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58259\/doctor-who-extra-s01e03-robot-of-sherwood-pdtv-x264-deadpool\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E03 Robot Of Sherwood PDTV x264-DEADPOOL (124.73 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "3",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:DZ7H4EWP2XW6YRYIXEIPMULETLASGDAF&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.PDTV.x264-DEADPOOL&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "4": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58251\/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-webrip-x264-c4tv\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek Webrip x264-C4TV (81.13 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "2",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:OZ7O2O3FE7RADBGOAJEE4UMBROPO7CW7&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        },
        "5": {
            "link": "https:\/\/eztv-proxy.net\/\/ep\/58252\/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-720p-webrip-x264-c4tv\/",
            "name": "Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek 720p Webrip x264-C4TV (203.70 MB)",
            "season": "1",
            "episode": "2",
            "magnet": "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FQ6CNHRGQSRKFWIX63JGG4KWLVVOZJQX&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.720p.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80"
        }
```

Comment: You have double entries. How should that work?

Comment: I have double entries because there are 2 different versions of episodes sometimes.

Comment: Hire a developer or try and come back with a minimal example of what you have tried and what did not go as expected. This site is not a "here is my code, now give me suggestion to fix it" you should have a minimal understanding of what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to implement a custom sort via [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Something along the lines of this:

```
$episodelist = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache/episodes.json'), true);

foreach ($episodelist as &$show) {
    usort($show, function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a["season"] == $b["season"]) {
                if ($a["episode"] == $b["episode"]) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($a["episode"] > $b["episode"]) ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return ($a["season"] > $b["season"]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    );
}

var_export($episodelist);
```

#### Output:

```
array (
    'doctor who (2005)' =>
        array (
            0 =>
                array (
                    'link' => 'https://eztv-proxy.net//ep/58248/doctor-who-2005-s08e03-hdtv-x264-tla/',
                    'name' => 'Doctor Who 2005 S08E03 HDTV x264-TLA (399.11 MB)',
                    'season' => '8',
                    'episode' => '3',
                    'magnet' => 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:SYDVQP4NMZJ5MQ2CEIOPZWUBLQWNKKHO&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.S08E03.HDTV.x264-TLA&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp://open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80',
                ),
            1 =>
                array (
                    'link' => 'https://eztv-proxy.net//ep/58254/doctor-who-2005-8x03-robot-of-sherwood-720p-hdtv-x264-fov/',
                    'name' => 'Doctor Who 2005 8x03 Robot Of Sherwood 720p HDTV x264-FoV (1.02 GB)',
                    'season' => '8',
                    'episode' => '3',
                    'magnet' => 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:S25AOAFO5ZUGXMZ52ZI2OUD5S5TD4ZBI&dn=Doctor.Who.2005.8x03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.720p.HDTV.x264-FoV&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp://open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80',
                ),
            2 =>
                array (
                    'link' => 'https://eztv-proxy.net//ep/58259/doctor-who-extra-s01e03-robot-of-sherwood-pdtv-x264-deadpool/',
                    'name' => 'Doctor Who Extra S01E03 Robot Of Sherwood PDTV x264-DEADPOOL (124.73 MB)',
                    'season' => '1',
                    'episode' => '3',
                    'magnet' => 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:DZ7H4EWP2XW6YRYIXEIPMULETLASGDAF&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E03.Robot.Of.Sherwood.PDTV.x264-DEADPOOL&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp://open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80',
                ),
            3 =>
                array (
                    'link' => 'https://eztv-proxy.net//ep/58252/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-720p-webrip-x264-c4tv/',
                    'name' => 'Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek 720p Webrip x264-C4TV (203.70 MB)',
                    'season' => '1',
                    'episode' => '2',
                    'magnet' => 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:FQ6CNHRGQSRKFWIX63JGG4KWLVVOZJQX&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.720p.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp://open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80',
                ),
            4 =>
                array (
                    'link' => 'https://eztv-proxy.net//ep/58251/doctor-who-extra-s01e02-into-the-dalek-webrip-x264-c4tv/',
                    'name' => 'Doctor Who Extra S01E02 Into The Dalek Webrip x264-C4TV (81.13 MB)',
                    'season' => '1',
                    'episode' => '2',
                    'magnet' => 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:OZ7O2O3FE7RADBGOAJEE4UMBROPO7CW7&dn=Doctor.Who.Extra.S01E02.Into.The.Dalek.Webrip.x264-C4TV&tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.istole.it:80&tr=udp://open.demonii.com:80&tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:80',
                ),
        ),
)
```

Comment: It does't work for me, I get the same array as before.

Comment: array ( 'doctor who (2005)' =>  array (  0 =>  array (  'link' => 'somelink',  'name' => 'name',  'season' => '1',  'episode' => '1',  'magnet' => 'magnet_link'  )

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a `usort()` with the following comperator function:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return $a['season'] * 1000 + $a['episode'] < $b['season'] * 1000 + $b['episode'] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

### Explanation

The `usort` function uses the provided function as a comparator to decide which of the elements is first. This way it orders all elements. I'am not sure if you have to reverse it. If that is the case, just replace the `<` with an `>`.  I use the factor `1000` to make the season parameter stronger than the episode paramter. I assume that there are never more than 999 episodes per season.

### Edit

Of course you need to use `json_decode` to convert the json string to an php array.

### Edit 2

Added inline if statement to make it work properly (? 1 : -1)

Comment: I'm using it like this right now, but it only returns 1: print_r(usort($episodelist, function($a, $b){return ($a['season'] * 1000 + $a['episode']) < ($b['season'] * 1000 + $b['episode']);}));